# Is there a way to get a list of projects and API calls associated with a user's Google Workspace account?

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk

I'm performing a large clean up of Google Workspace accounts and I'd like to programmatically determine whether any of the accounts have projects associated with them, and if so, when the last API calls associated with that project were made. Is there any way to do this programmatically via the Google Admin (or some other) APIs? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... probably ;-)

This is a naive solution and I will be interested to see better ways to do this.

**Please run this on a subset of your Projects and Users to ensure it addresses your need**

For you to consider:

- You write "Projects" but identities can be bound to many Google Cloud resources (Organizations, Folders, Buckets etc.) too
- How many Projects and Users are there?
- `serviceAccount:` should be excluded but what about other [identities](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#concepts_related_identity)?
- We'll filter by log entries for `user:` (?) currently in a Project Policy.

###### Org Admin

You'll need to use an Org Admin identity.

###### List all Projects

```bash
PROJECTS=$(\
  gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")
for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  echo "Project: ${PROJECT}"
  ...
done
```

###### Get each Project's Policy's `user:`

Filter the policy by members of the form `user:{email}`

Extract the value `{email}` from `user:{email}`

```bash
USERS=$(\
  gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} \
  --flatten="bindings[].members[]" \
  --filter="bindings.members:user" \
  --format="value(bindings.members.split(\":\").slice(1:))")
echo "Users: ${USERS}"
```

###### Filter [Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit) actually [Admin Activity Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#admin-activity)

Grep the activity logs for the last 30 days for the most recent (!) log entry for this user.

```bash
for USER in ${USERS}
do
  echo "User: ${USER}"
  FILTER="
    logName=\"projects/${PROJECT}/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity\"
    protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail=\"${USER}\"
  "
  LOG=$(gcloud logging read "${FILTER}" \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --freshness="30d" \
  --order=desc \
  --limit=1)
  printf "Log:\n%s" "${LOG}"
done
```